# Making 2 SwiperJS scripts work together - 2nd one not working when other init script is added to same page

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, swiper.js

Having trouble making 2 swiperJS Sliders work together.

The conflict seems to be in the  for each, or the JS column in codepen / the external script file that initializes the slider.

Anyone have any ideas on how i can get them both to work together? For example, if you take the script from the 2nd one, and put it into the script column in slider one you'll see it breaks it. Or, if you do the opposite, it breaks it too.

It doesn't look like it's a matter of them both being called .swiper-container because the 2nd one ID's the swiper with #swiper1

[SLIDER 1: Codepen](https://codepen.io/jw-op-1/pen/jOzdwbG)

[SLIDER 2: Codepen](https://codepen.io/jw-op-1/pen/gOeqYLV)
The JS that makes this one work is:

```
(function () {
  'use strict';
  const mySwiper = new Swiper('#swiper1', {
    loop: true,
    autoplay: 4000,
    slidesPerView: '1',
    centeredSlides: true,

    a11y: true,
    keyboardControl: true,
    grabCursor: true,

    // pagination
    pagination: '.swiper-pagination',
    paginationClickable: true,

    // navigation arrows
    nextButton: '#js-prev1',
    prevButton: '#js-next1' });

})();
```

any help would be appreciated!

If you look at both Codepen's it'd be most helpful i'm thinking.

slider 1 works great and i dont want to mess with that one as it's telling it to show a certain amount of slides per view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is complete working example https://jsfiddle.net/710x569p/ As i told you in another answer don't use same selector and exclude **#swiper1** from **.swiper-container**

```
var mySwiper = new Swiper('.swiper-container:not(#swiper1)'
```

Comment: Perfect -- looks like its working -- thank you! - i thought you meant to replace this ( const mySwiper = new Swiper('#swiper1', {)  with that line.

If i have another swiperJS slider on the site in the same script.js file, how would it look to do another one? 

would it be somehting like:

var mySwiper = new Swiper('.swiper-container:not(#swiper1)', '.swiper-container:not(#swiper2)', { 

?

Comment: and i'm guessing in order to style it so it doesn't affect the other one i have to either target the parent class (let's say its .about-slide, then i'd make it .about-slide .slider-container {width: x; height: x) right? otherwise ti looks like it's affecting the 1st codepen with the 3 slides if i dont.

Comment: .swiper-container means you want to create swiper for all that classes on the page. You better add id swiper0 and change the original swiper code to new Swiper('#swiper0'. It will make easier to add new swipers if they have different configuration. It is also helpful if you want to style them - apply all styles from that id like #swiper0 .swiper-slide

Comment: Thanks @taras -- are you able to show me what that looks like on the JSFiddle you had put together?

Comment: Sure https://jsfiddle.net/cgahjf7m/

Comment: i see what u mean now... makes more sense especially if we're going to be using different swiperJS types on the site. Thanks @taras !